# Grunt run by Teamcity does not properly output to log

Tags: node.js, batch-file, continuous-integration, gruntjs, teamcity

I have a teamcity build running grunt as a command line task.

When I execute `grunt default` the output (in the Teamcity logs) does not contain the relevant error output from grunt. It do however return the appropriate non-zero exit code, which cause the teamcity build to fail correctly. I do not get the grunt error log though.

This page: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-teamcity describes the following workaround for the issue that I'm facing:

> Teamcity on windows does not flush the stdout stream before exiting
>   the grunt node process. There has been some work around this in both
>   nodejs and grunt, but it is by no means resolved. If you see missing
>   output in your Teamcity build log then try running the grunt task
>   using the TC command line runner by redirecting output to a file, e.g:
>
> grunt default --no-color > grunt.tmp & type grunt.tmp & del grunt.tmp
>   Seems that by redirecting to a file the output is synchronous, whereas
>   with pipe (or TC plugin execute method) the output is async and not
>   captured before the node process exits.

So it basically suggest that you run grunt like this: `grunt default --no-color > grunt.tmp & type grunt.tmp & del grunt.tmp`. The problem with this approach however is that is always return 0 (zero) as the exit code, which mean that my Teamcity build does not properly fail.

I imagine this can be fixed with some creative batch scripting, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

:: prepare environment
setlocal enableextensions
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.grunt.tmp"

:: run grunt
call grunt default --no-color > "%tempFile%"

:: Keep the grunt exit code
set "exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%"

:: Print the grunt output
type "%tempFile%"

:: cleanup and exit with adecuated value
del /q "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Comment: Thanks guys, have updated the readme on https://github.com/johnhunter/grunt-teamcity/

Answer (score 0):

```
call grunt default --no-color > temp.txt

type temp.txt
```

Comment: Will this retain the proper exit code from the grunt call?